# JPanel Location and Size changing weird

Tags: java, location, jpanel, size, pong

I'm about to program a little version of "Pong". But I've already got a problem with my `JPanels`. The size of the `Shields` is changing pretty weird to 10 from 100. And there is no method that changes the size of it!
Also the Shields jump to the upper middle of the `JPanel`. They aren't expect to do that. Seen on the two screenshots at the ent of the post. (Puu.sh)

Sorry if I'm just missing something obvious, but as I said, I'm training.

Main with psvm()

```
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Field();
}

}
```

Field (Frame with the Game in it)

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ComponentAdapter;
import java.awt.event.ComponentEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import java.awt.event.MouseListener;

import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class Field extends JFrame {

private Room room = new Room();

public Field() {

    this.setSize((int) (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth() / 1.5), (int) (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() / 1.5));
    this.setLayout(null);
    this.setLocation((int) ((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth() - (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getWidth() / 1.5)) / 2), (int) ((Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() - (Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize().getHeight() / 1.5)) / 2));
    this.getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
    this.setResizable(true);
    this.setEnabled(true);
    this.setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000, 455));
    if (getHeight() < 455) {
        this.setSize(getWidth(), 455);
    } else if (getWidth() < 1000) {
        this.setSize(1000, getHeight());
    }

    this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);


    this.add(room);

    this.setVisible(true);
    addMouseListener(this);

    this.addComponentListener(new ComponentAdapter() {
        public void componentResized(ComponentEvent evt) {
            room.updateLocation(getSize());
        }
    });


}

}
```

Room

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
public class Room extends JPanel {


private Shield shieldL = new Shield(0); // LEFT side
private Shield shieldR = new Shield(1); // RIGHT side

public Room() {

    this.setBackground(new Color(122, 197, 205));

    this.add(shieldL);
    this.add(shieldR);
}

public void updateLocation(Dimension d) {
    this.setSize((int) d.getWidth(), (int) (d.getHeight() - (d.getHeight() / 5)));
    this.setLocation(0, (int) (d.getHeight() / 10));
    shieldL.updateLocation(getSize());
    shieldR.updateLocation(getSize());
    this.setVisible(true);

}
}
```

Shield

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Shield extends JPanel {

private int side = 0;

public Shield(int s) { //0 = Left  |  1 = Right

    side = s;
    this.setSize(10, 100);
    this.setBackground(Color.white);

}

public void updateLocation(Dimension d) {   //Bug found here
    System.out.println(getSize());          //Bug seems not to be created here?
    int xPos;
    if (side == 0) {
        xPos = (int) (d.getWidth() / 8);
    } else {
        xPos = (int) (d.getWidth() / 8 * 7 - this.getWidth() / 2);
    }
    this.setLocation(xPos, (int) (d.getHeight() / 2 - (getHeight() / 2)));
    this.setVisible(true);
}

}
```

They end up like this:, switching the location at randome framesize changings.

http://puu.sh/ceyE0/ef15ee1748.png

http://puu.sh/ceyFN/122174db48.png

Thanks!
Julian :)

Comment: How can we find the problem when the code you post does not compile for us? Please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) (and make sure it's *minimal and compileable*).

Comment: Whole Code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/1ee36b3ef2da779e2f76

Comment: You are ignoring my comment, read it again please including the link and if something is not clear then ask. There are some standards expected for a question on SO.

Comment: Minimal code: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/770c619d0c5ee3e6b0b5

Just run psvm()

Comment: Very good. Please edit your question to include this minimal code instead of the current one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `Shield`, change the line

```
setSize(10, 100);
```

to

```
setPreferredSize(new Dimension(10, 100));
```

Do not use `setSize` methods, they are called internally.

**Edit:**

Try only these 2 classes:

```
public class Field extends JFrame {

    private Room room = new Room();

    public Field() {

        //Mock panel
        JPanel filler = new JPanel();
        filler.setOpaque(false);

        getContentPane().setBackground(Color.GRAY);
        getContentPane().add(filler, BorderLayout.PAGE_START);
        getContentPane().add(room);

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setMinimumSize(new Dimension(1000, 455));
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        pack();
        room.init();
        setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

---

```
public class Room extends JPanel {

    private static int leftWidth = 100;
    private static int leftHeight = 100;
    private static int leftX;
    private static int leftY;

    private static int rightWidth = 100;
    private static int rightHeight = 100;
    private static int rightX;
    private static int rightY;

    public Room() {

        setBackground(new Color(122, 197, 205));
    }

    void init() {

        leftX = getWidth() / 8;
        leftY = getHeight() / 2 - leftHeight / 2;
        rightX = getWidth() * 7 / 8;
        rightY = getHeight() / 2 - rightHeight / 2;
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2d.setColor(Color.WHITE);
        g2d.fillRect(leftX, leftY, leftWidth, leftHeight);
        g2d.fillRect(rightX, rightY, rightWidth, rightHeight);
    }
}
```

Comment: The `getWidth()` in `init()` at `Room` gets the width of the Frame, right? but where does it get the reference? #neverusedinit #googletellsmecomplicatedstuff

Comment: @JulianE. It gets the width of `room` because the call is from inside `Room`.

Comment: Ok, so this method is predefined and always gives that reference?

Comment: Everything works and i think i understood how to do it. Now i created a new class for a `Scoreboard`, pretty similar to `Room`but how can i get that `Scoreboard` infront of all other `Graphics`?

Comment: @JulianE. That is probably worth its own question since this one is about fixing the shields. The panel `filler` is for you to replace with whatever you wanted to be there.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you do not understand Layout Managers and how they treat or use setSize, setPreferredSize, setMinimumSize, and setMaximumSize methods.

For your panel class, setSize does not work because when you create a JPanel, it uses FlowLayout as the default layout manager and layout managers ignore size specified by the setSize method.  You must use the others in some combination (at least one).  The only way you can use setSize is for Components that do not assign a layout manager by default OR, by invoking setLayout(null).  This is called Absolute Positioning.  This is where you MUST specify the location AND size of each component.

Search the Java Swing tutorial and search for "How to use Layout Managers."  If you are using Swing, it is IMPERATIVE that you understand this concept because different Layout Managers obey different size and positioning rules.  For example, Flow Layout and Grid Layout behave very differently.

Of course, Absolute Positioning is a pain, but it is the method that offers you absolute control of size and positioning of Swing components.  But understanding Layout Managers and using them properly can save you a lot of time creating your GUI's.

***** UPDATED INFO *****
The problem with resizing the frame is due to the fact your panel is using FlowLayout.  This layout manager allows the rearrangement of components in the panel. There are several ways to fix this problem.  One is to use a layout manager that preserves the aspect ratio of the component when it is resized.  For example, GridLayout "breaks down" a component into grids.  If you think of a checker board, it is an 8x8 grid.  If you make the panel a perfect square, then all grids will be squares of equal size.  When you resize a panel, the aspect ratio of the panel (not necessarily the inner components), is kept.  Another way, and maybe your best alternative while you learn how to use layout managers properly, is to prevent resizing of the frame.

Comment: Ok, then i'll try that and Comment again if i don't find a solution

Comment: Just remember, only use setSize method if you are using Absolute Positioning. the best way to guarantee this is the case (i.e. you are not sure which components set a default layout manager) is to invoke setLayout(null) on each component class.  And, also understand how the pack(); method works.  If your components' bounds are not set properly, it will not work as intended.